# jquery selector for elements beside one another?

Tags: jquery

this SHOULD be simple, but I have been through the [Jquery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) help for about an hour now and nothing seems to be working. Help!

I am basically trying to pull the text (an address) of a SPAN after a user clicks on the link next to it.  Please note though, I will have about 10 on a page, so I cannot set a static address. It must be pulled when the user clicks.

**The html code:**

```
<a href="3" class="clicky">Click to Show Map</a> 
<span style="display: none" class="theaddy">123 Fake Street, Somewhere Else, 12341</span>
```

So really, my question is, how do I grab the text from `.theaddy` when a user clicks on `.clicky`?

As I said, I *cannot* use

```
 var propertyaddy = $(.theaddy).text();
```

because there are 10 of these addy's on the same page.  I need some sort of "THIS" > Next To kinda thing.

I also tossed around the idea of placing the SPAN inside the A, but my efforts on that weren't working either.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the next sibling of any element.

```
$('.clicky').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).next().text();
    ...
});
```

So long as your required `.theaddy` element is always the "next" element there's no need to give a specific class selector inside the `.next()` call.

If there might be other elements in between, you can use `.nextAll('.theaddy').first()`.   This generates a list of all following `.theAddy` elements, and then takes the first such element.

Comment: I'm up-voting purely because you added the `nextAll()` method, as I was doing the same. And, at that point, it *felt* like plagiarism to add it to my own answer as well. =)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `next()`:

```
text = $(this).next('.theaddy').text();
```

In the above code I've used a selector that will only grab the next element if it's of `class='theaddy'`, without that selector it'll just grab the text of *any* element that follows the `.clicky` element in the mark-up.

Incidentally, when you're looking for methods to *traverse* the DOM, you need to look at the [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), rather than the selectors.

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: @PaulHanak this answer doesn't correctly show how to reference the element next to the clicked element.  It does exactly what you said you cannot use.

Comment: @Alnitak, yeah: I'd forgotten it was meant to be inside the click-handler. Darn... =/

Comment: How so very simple! TRAVERSING methods. That term will definitely help with future endeavors. Thank you David. I do see what you two mean though. I cannot use .theaddy simply because there are multiple elements named that.